# Can the default timeslot height be set in FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

It looks like the default is 20px, but I was hoping to bump this up, so an event that is the length of 1 timeslot would be able to show the event header and body. Currently when an event is the length of 1 timeslot only the event header is shown.

Comment: In fullcalendar.css you can change this line to adjust the timeslot height .fc-agenda-slots td div { height: 20px; }. So if you your shortest event is half the timeslot length (30min event, but 1hr timeslot) you would double this value.

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fullcalendar.css you can change this line to adjust the timeslot height

```
.fc-agenda-slots td div { height: 20px; }
```

So if you your shortest event is half the timeslot length (30min event, but 1hr timeslot) you would double this value

---

CAVEAT: As pointed out by jjnguy this change will break the drag/drop and resize functionality. It solves the problem of changing the default timeslot height though.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution. After doing this it looks like dragging and resizing are broken.

Comment: You are correct. Not ideal, but drag/drop and resize weren't requirements for us.

Comment: In newer version (3.8.0), css selector name is changed to: `.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td { height: 2.5em }`

Answer (score 14):

Fullcalendar Version 5

```css
.fc-timegrid-slot {
    height: 30em; // 1.5em by default
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I had to add !important after changing the height em, just for future reference.

Comment: Isn't this useless in FC V5 since it supports [expandRows](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/expandRows)

Comment: You should also need to change the line-height

Answer (score 9):

Anyone still looking for the answer in new versions.
In the new version (v3.9.0), change the css to:

```
.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
  height: 2em; // Change This to your required height
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

NOTE: this does not affect the drag-drop or resizing for me.

Comment: @robin Tak, This works like a charm. If one needs to lower it to e.g. 1.5em, then the `slotLabel`s will take up too much room and make the slots different in heights. This can be fixed by setting `.fc-axis {font-size: 0.7em;}`.